# how hide the facebook contents until the user like the page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

im trying to get a code to make my Facebook page contents hide until the user like the page (simply change the page content after like)

I created a Facebook application about one year ago and it works well and did what i want https://www.facebook.com/app.graphicano/app_1417521298482387

**the Problem:**i created a new application and used the same code put its not working 
https://www.facebook.com/app.graphicano/app_711341728921627?ref=page_internal

The code i'm using

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';  //download at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/downloads

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'APP ID', // enter your App's ID
  'secret' => 'Secret', // enter your App's Secret
  'cookie' => true,
));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>

<?
// Did they like a page?
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

//echo $signed_request.'<br>';
print_r ($data);
if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
// DISPLAY TO: those who didn't LIKE the page
    ?>

<!-- Didn't Like -->

NON fan page

<!-- End of Didn't Like -->
    <?
} else {
?>
    Its a fan page
<? } ?>
```

i need to solve this problem as soon as possible 
thanks

Comment: Next time, please use the search function of StackOverflow before posting a question and consult the Facebook docs. It's all there.

Comment: yeah, that same questions gets asked WAY too many times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like gating is not possible and not allowed anymore, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Older Apps will still have that "liked" parameter, but they will always return "true" after 5th of November.